# freezing row header and first three column of table using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I really confused about freezing table row header and column using css and JavaScript. In my project i want freeze first row header and also first three columns using only css and JavaScript not by Jquery.
so please anyone can help me for this work. thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code ,what you tried?

Comment: Do you have example code of your attempt at this?  A lot of solutions that I have seen use additional tables to emulate this.

Comment: please check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5x7u9ggw/
    
this will work properly in internet explorer8 also